# ORA-04092: cannot ROLLBACK in a trigger after exceeding number of applications made daily

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

May I know how a trigger would be written if lets say there are applicant, position, applies relations and applies is like the association class as an applicant can apply many position and a position can by applied by many applicants and the applies relation has its own attribute called dateApp and I want to limit the amount of applications to twice a day, so this means a customer can only apply 2 items in one day. So far I have this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APPLYTWICEONLY
AFTER INSERT ON APPLIES
DECLARE
CURSOR C IS
SELECT ANUMBER, COUNT(APPDATE) AS TOTAL
FROM APPLIES
WHERE APPDATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY ANUMBER;
BEGIN


FOR APPLY IN C
LOOP

   IF APPLY.TOTAL > 2 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AN APPLICANT CAN APPLY MAXIMUM TWICE A DAY.');
      ROLLBACK;
   END IF;
END LOOP;


END;
/
```

so what is happening here is, after an applicant applies for a position, i check the total number of applications made today for each applicant using the anumber, if the total applications exceed 2 for an applicant today, then i will roll back and undo that insert. I want to do this using a statement  trigger instead of a row trigger, but i keep getting ORA-04092: cannot ROLLBACK in a trigger, after an applicant has exceeded the number of applications for the day. Can someone help me?

Comment: try to replace `AFTER INSERT` with `BEFORE INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run COMMIT or ROLLBACK in a trigger:

```
$ oerr ora 4092
04092, 00000, "cannot %s in a trigger"
// *Cause: A trigger attempted to commit or rollback.
// *Action: Rewrite the trigger so it does not commit or rollback.
$
```

Comment: Did you at least *read* what I wrote in that example? Where exactly did I say that it **is** a solution or that it should be done? I'm just commenting (after all, that's what *comments* are for) that what you said isn't entirely true, nothing else.

Comment: I have read it and I consider an bad answer to OP question. If this a comment you should post this as comment and not as an anwser.

Comment: And that's perfectly OK, no problem with that. The OP has a problem and we are willing to spare some time trying to assist. As usual, there are several options one can choose. However, I think that you didn't read what I wrote carefully enough. Anyway, this is a futile discussion and I'm out of it. Have a nice day.

Comment: A better answer would have been what you wrote in your comment for `raise_application_error` usage.

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing business logic via database triggers is most often wrong approach.

You should do that check where *applicant applies for a position* and either let it proceed or stop the application process.

---

As of triggers being unable to `commit` or `rollback`; well, that's not *entirely* true. If it (a trigger) is an autonomous transaction, it can. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_rlbk
  2    after insert on test
  3  declare
  4    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  5  begin
  6    rollback;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2

SQL>
```

As you can see, the main transaction wasn't rolled back - `ID = 2` was inserted into the table. What would have been rolled back, would be code contained within the trigger itself. There's none in my example, on purpose, to show you that such a pragma won't help in what you're trying to do.

Also, the fact that you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should* do it.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. and also this is homework, i have to use trigger to enforce this constraint, may I know how can i stop the application process?

Comment: If *everything else* works, then - instead of ROLLBACK - use `raise_application_error(-20000, 'An applicant can apply maximum twice a day');`

Comment: may I know what is the -20000? must I always put that number?

Comment: Please do not hijack this discussion. Yes you can in a autonomous transactions. But is using an autonomous transaction the right answer to OP question ? I really doubt. Try to convince OP that this the right solution to its problem. Waiting for something more constructive from your side ...

Comment: @Astoach167: error codes from -20000 to -20999 are reserved for us, developers. You can pick any of those, no problem. I took the first value.

Comment: @Astoach167 - "this is homework".  We see this all the time. ALL THE TIME!  Instructors give a problem with the stipulation that a certain technique be used (quite often this happens with triggers).  I guess their intention is to get the student to learn _HOW_ to use a certain feature or technique. But the also inadvertently teach the neophyte that the given feature/technique is a good solution to the underlying _business problem_. ... when it is actually a very very poor use case.  Deal with the assignment as you must be be aware that this is NOT how to write an application.